# Unable to retrieve option tag attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Since I want to get the `companyTitle` when a user selects something from the dropdown menu. I have defined it like this `data-description="${companyTitle}"` as shown in the code below of the success function of my Ajax call.

```
success : function(data) {
                 $.each(data.personnelData.reverse(), function (i) { 
                     
                     let companyId = data.personnelData[i].companyId;
                     let companyTitle = data.personnelData[i].title;
                     let dateOfCreation = moment(data.personnelData[i].createDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                     
                 
                $("#myList").append(`<option data-description="${companyTitle}" value="${companyId}">${companyTitle}|${dateOfCreation}</option>`); 
                                        
                });
               
                
                
         },
```

When I tested it like this in my javascript code:

```
$("select#myList").change(function(){
        
        console.log("Testing companyTitle");
        console.log($('#myList :selected').data('description'));
        
        
     })
```

I only saw the following in the console log - `Company Set for`

And I believe it is because of the following:

When I inspected the option tag in the browser, It showed me the following entry:

```
<option data-description="Company Set for " abc="" pxy="" psqrty@12:20:49"="" (4="" companies="" on="" 09="" 22="" 2020="" 01:20:53="" pm)"="" value="12345">Company Set for "Abc Pxy Psqrty@12:20:49" (4 companies on 09/22/2020 01:20:53 PM)|09/22/2020</option>
```

How can I fix this so that inside `$("select#myList").change(function(){` I can retrieve only the part inside the double quotes (i.e. `Abc Pxy Psqrty@12:20:49`) of the following `companyTitle`:

`Company Set for "Abc Pxy Psqrty@12:20:49" (4 companies on 09/22/2020 01:20:53 PM)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When data in the `data.personnelData[i].title` always similar and has only one pair of double quotes you can split that string like:

```js
var companyTitle = "Company Set for \"Abc Pxy Psqrty@12:20:49\" (4 companies on 09/22/2020 01:20:53 PM)";

var companyTitleDescription = companyTitle.indexOf('"') > -1 ?  companyTitle.split("\"")[1] : companyTitle;

console.log(companyTitleDescription);
```

and assign that to your `data-description` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. I just realized that since Jan 2020, I have records with the format `Company Set for "Abc Pxy Psqrty@12:20:49" (4 companies on 09/22/2020 01:20:53 PM)` and 
 for 2019 records, I have data in the form of just `Abc Pxy Psqrty@12:20:49`. How should differentiate between the two cases and still grab those records ?

Comment: you can check if record includes double quotes and split it if yes, and if no then leave at it is.

Comment: Ok, something like this `
 if((str.indexOf('"') > -1))
{
    //Code here
}` ?

Comment: yeap like that, I have updated my answer, and if it solves your issue you can accept it

Comment: Could you take a look at this JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1kr4ftc8/1/    It's showing `undefined` for input like `Companyspecific (a@10:30:20`

Comment: sorry I've made a mistype, you should use `companyTitle.indexOf('"') > -1` instead of `companyTitle.indexOf('"' > -1)`, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If rather than building your `option` using string concatenation, you build it using jQuery's object model the description data does not get garbled because of the quotes:

```js
const companyTitle = "Company Set for \"Abc Pxy Psqrty@12:20:49\" (4 companies on 09/22/2020 01:20:53 PM)",
    companyId = 1,
    dateOfCreation = "01/01/2020";
    
                
const $option = $('<option />')
  .val(companyId)
  .text(`${companyTitle}|${dateOfCreation}`)
  .data('description',companyTitle);

$('#myList').append($option);


$('#myList').on('change', function(){
  console.log($(":selected", this).data('description'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myList">
  <option>Select</option>
</select>
```

If you then want to extract just the bit in quotes that should be fairly straightforward - use regex or string manipulation. There are plenty of examples of extracting the value between quotes.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. I just realized that since Jan 2020, I have records with the format `Company Set for "Abc Pxy Psqrty@12:20:49" (4 companies on 09/22/2020 01:20:53 PM)` and 
 for 2019 records, I have data in the form of just `Abc Pxy Psqrty@12:20:49`. How should differentiate between the two cases and still grab those records ?